# JDBC executeQuery always throws exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm using jdbc.Driver to get a connection and then use a prepared statement to get a table from a mySQL instance.

For some reason every  preparedStatement.executeQuery(); throws a "Before start of result set" exception even before I try to use the resultSet.

Here is the example code for the main class

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection mySQLConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/operations", "user", "password");
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = mySQLConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM operations.feature_properties LIMIT 0,1000");

       ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
       //Exception is thrown by the previous line without using the result set
        mySQLConnection.close();
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The call stack is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.checkRowPos(ResultSet.java:720)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getInt(ResultSet.java:2617)
at sqlReader.SQLReader.main(SQLReader.java:23)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use result.next() before you can access the result

Comment: I've tried that, the exception is thrown during the executeStatment() and not if I try to use the resultSet

Comment: the exception tell us that happend during a `ResultSet.getInt` call in your `sqlReader.SQLReader.migrateFeaturePropertiesTable` method. Just call `resultSet.next()` to put yourself on the first row. Stacktrace don't lie ;)

Comment: Nope, here I get the exception thrown before the resultSet is even used

Comment: Please post the complete method. Also what is the line 74 ? I bet it is something like `int i = resultSet.getInt(1);` The stacktrace can't lie, it is not coming from `Statement.executeQuery` or it would be in the stacktrace. It come from `at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getInt(ResultSet.java:2617)` call from `at sqlReader.SQLReader.migrateFeaturePropertiesTable(SQLReader.java:74)`

Comment: I've added the entire code, you're welcome to take a look

Comment: You are not utilizing resultSet for anything. There is no any purpose of this code.

Comment: That's irrelevant, I want to try and use the resultSet in the future. for now I should be able to at least retrieve it without throwing the exception

Comment: @KeyurPanchal that's a [mcve] ... don't expect it to have any sense, it just show what the problem is (that a perfect example by the way). But to stay on the subject ... the stacktrace and the code don't match... there is no trace of `ResultSet.executeQuery` and that `ResultSet.getInt` should not be there. Clean your project ... (that's my only guess)

Comment: The code you show **cannot** produce the exception stacktrace in your question; show your actual code, or show the real exception.

Comment: @AxelH: I am telling this because of the same reason that you have mentioned. Exception Trace and Code Sample that has been shared is not at all matching. Without accessing the ResultSet, how can anyone in the world get Exception related to ResultSet ?

Comment: @KeyurPanchal you said "_You are not utilizing resultSet for anything. There is no any purpose of this code._", nothing about the Stacktrace that don't match. Just be clearer next time ;)